# Trouble with scrolling through several panels in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I want to be able to have a set of panels of vertical panels that remain the same size, but I want to have a vertical scroll bar that will allow me to scroll in the window.  Right now I'm using a wx.ScrolledPanel and adding panels to that and putting them in the sizer but nothing really shows up on the screen

```
import wx
import  wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled
class josh(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, id):   
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, wx.GetApp().TopWindow, title='Title',size=(800,600))
    arr= ['Q1.......','Q2.......','Q3.......','Q4.......','Q5.......','Q6.......','Q7..............','Q8..........']
    scroll=scrolled.ScrolledPanel(self, -1)
    #scroll.SetScrollbars(1,1,1,1) 
    panelList = []
    commentList = []
    count = 1
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    for p in arr: 
        panelList.append(wx.Panel(scroll ,-1, size = (800,100), style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER))
        sizer.Add(panelList[count-1], 1, wx.EXPAND)
        wx.StaticText(panelList[count-1], -1, str(count), (5, 50), wx.DefaultSize) 
        commentList.append( wx.TextCtrl(panelList[count-1], style=wx.TE_MULTILINE,pos=(500, 20),size = (200,50)))
        count+=1



    self.SetAutoLayout(True)
    self.SetSizer(sizer)
    scroll.SetupScrolling()
if __name__=='__main__':
app=wx.App(False)
frame=josh(parent=None,id=-1)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have each panel as a child widget to the scrolled widget. BUT you add each panel to sizer and then mistakenly set the Frame's sizer to the sizer named "sizer".

This is a mismatch which will pretty much always have bad visual effects.

You should either set scrolled.SetSizer(sizer)
or make a new sizer, say call it framesizer and then add scrolled to it. THEN self.SetSizer(framesizer) where self if the josh() frame.

Also the ScrolledPanel will not show it's scroll bars unless the child widgets are larger then the ScrolledPanel.

```
# Broken down here to show sizer child-parent hiearchy 
# AND widget child-parent hiearchy need to be congruent

import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel
scrolled = wx.lib.scrolledpanel #i use reload(...) in pyslices.py


class Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, color='black'):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, size=(800,100))

        # several "Panels" sized added together 
        # are bigger than ScrolledPanel size

        self.SetMinSize( (800, 100) )
        self.SetBackgroundColour( color )

        widget1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        widget2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add( widget1, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 15 )
        sizer.Add( widget2, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 15 )

        self.SetSizer( sizer )


class BigPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):

        # at least one child widget or aggregate width 
        # of several child widgets has to be wider than 
        # ScrolledPanel to show its horizontal scroll bar

        # at least one child widget or aggregate height
        # of more then one child widget has to be "taller" than
        # the height of the ScrolledPanel for it to show
        # its vertical scroll bar

        # -------------------------------------V---V
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, size=(800,800))
        # -------------------------------------^---^

        panel0 = Panel(self, 'black')
        panel1 = Panel(self, 'red')
        panel2 = Panel(self, 'green')
        panel3 = Panel(self, 'blue')
        panel4 = Panel(self, 'white')
        panel5 = Panel(self, 'purple')

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        sizer.Add( panel0, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 15 )
        sizer.Add( panel1, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 15 )
        sizer.Add( panel2, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 15 )
        sizer.Add( panel3, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 15 )
        sizer.Add( panel4, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 15 )
        sizer.Add( panel5, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 15 )

        self.SetSizer( sizer )


class ScrolledPanel(scrolled.ScrolledPanel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        # ---------------------------------------------------V---V
        scrolled.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent, size=(400,400))
        # ---------------------------------------------------^---^

        bigpanel = BigPanel(self)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add( bigpanel, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 15 )

        self.SetSizer( sizer )
        self.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.SetupScrolling()


class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent = wx.GetApp().GetTopWindow(),
            title = 'Trouble with scrolling through several panels in wxpython',
            size = (500,400))

        scroll = ScrolledPanel(self)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add( scroll, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 15 )
        self.SetSizer( sizer )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.GetApp()
    if not app: app = wx.App(0)
    frame = Frame()
    frame.Show()
    if not app.IsMainLoopRunning():
        app.MainLoop()
```